# Custom NSFormatter in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to write my own custom formatter in Objective C by subclassing NSNumberFormatter. Specifically what I'd like to do is make a number turn red if it is above or below certain values. The [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/CreatingACustomFormatter.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000196-CJBFABHB) says

*For example, if you want negative financial amounts to appear in red, you have this method return a string with an attribute of red text. In attributedStringForObjectValue:withDefaultAttributes: get the non-attributed string by invoking stringForObjectValue: and then apply the proper attributes to that string.*

Based on this advice I implemented the following code

```
- (NSAttributedString*) attributedStringForObjectValue: (id)anObject withDefaultAttributes: (NSDictionary*)attr;
{
    NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[self stringForObjectValue:anObject]];

    if ([[attrString string] floatValue] < -20.0f) {
        [attrString addAttribute:@"NSForegroundColorAttributeName" value:[NSColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, 10)];
        return attrString;
    } else return attrString;
}
```

But when I test this all it does is freeze my application. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Does your number always have exactly 10 digits? You should probably use `NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length)` instead of `NSMakeRange(0, 10)`.

Comment: In the future, it would really help if you got a hang dump—or just ran in the debugger—and posted the result. Just saying it "freeze[s] my application" means everyone has to guess what might have gone wrong. In this case, the result is most likely an unhandled `NSRangeException`, but that's just a guess; the debugger would tell you that for sure, which would make the answer obvious.

Comment: Abarnet, sorry. You are right. I should have been more specific. I am still learning my way around the XCode debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I was finally able to implement this. To make it more visible when a number is negative, I decided to make the background of the text red with white text. The following code does work in a NSTextField cell. I'm not sure why the code in my question (and the answer) does not work, addAttribute should work.

```
- (NSAttributedString *)attributedStringForObjectValue:(id)anObject withDefaultAttributes:  (NSDictionary *)attributes{

    NSString *string = [self stringForObjectValue:anObject];
    NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string];
    NSInteger stringLength = [string length];

    if ([[attrString string] floatValue] < 0)
    {
         NSDictionary *firstAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [NSColor whiteColor],
                                      NSBackgroundColorAttributeName: [NSColor blueColor]};
    [attrString setAttributes:firstAttributes range:NSMakeRange(0, stringLength)];
}

return attrString;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe this has something to do with your `NSRange` that you create. I believe your length (10 in your example) is out of bounds. Try getting the length of the string that you use to initialize your `NSMutableAttributedString`.

For example:

```
- (NSAttributedString*) attributedStringForObjectValue: (id)anObject withDefaultAttributes: (NSDictionary*)attr;
{
    NSString *string = [self stringForObjectValue:anObject];
    NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string];
    NSInteger stringLength = [string length];

    if ([[attrString string] floatValue] < -20.0f)
    {
        [attrString addAttribute:@"NSForegroundColorAttributeName" value:[NSColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, stringLength)];
    }

    return attrString;
}
```

Comment: +1. The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html) explicitly says "Raises … an `NSRangeException` if any part of *aRange* lies beyond the end of the receiver's characters."

Comment: I made the changes you suggested and my application no longer "freezes". Thanks! Unfortunately no color seems to get applied to the text. The text is being displayed in an Form Cell with the Custom Formatter associated to it.

Comment: Perhaps you will need to log the attributed string object to the console so that you can ensure it is as you would expect it to be. Forgive me, I'm not that familiar with NSAttributedStrings.

Comment: You are right. With NSLog I can see that the string is in fact correct. Unfortunately the NSFormCell I am using to display the string may not support NSAttributedStrings but that is another problem. Thanks again for the help!